# Windows 7 64 Bit PC: Windows Updates Installed Yesterday & Cannot Now Boot-Up To Login?

Tags: windows-7, boot, restore

Everything was working fine until yesterday, when I installed Windows Updates, things went wrong.

PC now boots up into "old fashioned" dialogue box entitled startup repair. This fails to solve the problem.

Have tried system restore from both disc & built in options I believe. 3 restore points given on the 9th (Automatic Restore), 10th (Win Updates) & 11th (Win Updates).

Have tried all 3 and each time, an unspecified error has occurred during the process **0x8000ffff** as shown here:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2695585

Thank you for your assistance, I would like to restore my PC the way it was before updates were installed yesterday ?

Comment: Sounds like you have a faulty drive, and/or corrupted file system.  What's your actual, specific question to us?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I'd like to restore it the way it was before updates occurred.

Comment: That's obvious, but still not a question. :)  If your drive is faulty or corrupt, then you've most likely lost data andfiles on the computer are now damaged, so restoring isn't going to happen (at least not from that disk).  Test the file-system and disk;  If they can't be repaired, then rescue as much data from the faulty drive as possible, and replace the drive. Either way, to avoid problems due to the lost data showing up again, restore from an known-good external backup (if you have one), or just format, reinstall Windows and start re-installing your apps, then copy your data back.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Thanks for that. You say "Test the file system and disk". How do I do this ? How do I rescue data from the faulty drive (in the event cannot be repaired) ?

Comment: Those questions have been covered on here several times, and it's all well documented on the Internet.  Hints: Go to your HDD manufacturer's site to get their utilities for testing (if they offer any), and for Windows start with a read-only `chkdsk` (you may have to boot to Safe Mode, or form your Windows disk since you system won't login to normal mode). Make backups of important data FIRST (boot from a Linux LiveCD or something and copy data to an external drive, for example).

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

According to TECHIE007, you can boot with Linux LiveCD like SystemRescue to recover your data or to make a fix a disk problem. They are many tools who do that for example you can use Hiren's Boot CD to repair your disk.